# What is the downfall of using verifyNoMoreInteractions in each test?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

Mockito's verifyNoMoreInteractions Jdoc has a warning

> A word of warning: Some users who did a lot of classic,
>   expect-run-verify mocking tend to use verifyNoMoreInteractions() very
>   often, even in every test method. verifyNoMoreInteractions() is not
>   recommended to use in every test method. verifyNoMoreInteractions() is
>   a handy assertion from the interaction testing toolkit. Use it only
>   when it's relevant. Abusing it leads to overspecified, less
>   maintainable tests.

What is the downfall of using this method in any test that is mocked? Would you mind giving any examples where it makes tests unmaintainable and overspecified?

Comment: In most cases, testing that "when I do this, that should happen" is clear and sufficient. Testing that "nothing else happens" is usually useless, and that's what verifyNoMoreInteractions() does. And when that breaks because in reality, something unrelated and/or unimportant also happens, developers tend to start verifying this unrelated or unimportant interaction, polluting the original test whose responsibility was simply to assert that "when I do this, that should happen". At least that's my interpretation.

Comment: What if i use verifyNoMoreInteractions in every mocked interface that is injected to constructor of concrete class? For instance, i inject local and remote repositories to usecase classes in Android clean architecture? If i call verifyNoMoreInteractions on these interfaces, or in similar constructs, is it considered polluted and/or unmaintainable?

Comment: The world is not black and white. If you really think adding that check to you test is necessary for that test to make sense, then add it. If you don't, then don't add it.